# Could not load type 'GraphQL.Http.IDocumentWriter' from assembly 'GraphQL, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Tags: c#, .net, graphql, graphql-dotnet

The error happens when it reaches `services.AddGraphQL`.

I tried downgrading the version of [GraphQL to 2.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GraphQL/2.4.0) but then `FuncServiceProvider` stops working.

Here's what I have:

#### `MarketScheme.cs`

```cs
public class MarketScheme : Schema
{
   public MarketScheme(IServiceProvider provider) : base(provider)
   {
        Query = provider.GetRequiredService<AppQuery>();
   }
}
```

#### `Startup.cs`

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<marketContext>();

    services.AddScoped<IMarketRepository, MarketRepository>();

    services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();

    services.AddScoped<IServiceProvider>(provider => new FuncServiceProvider(provider.GetRequiredService));

    services.AddScoped<MarketScheme>();

    services.AddGraphQL(options =>
    {
        options.ExposeExceptions = true;
        options.EnableMetrics = true;
    }).AddGraphTypes(ServiceLifetime.Scoped);

    services.AddControllers();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to this.

1. The interface `GraphQL.Http.IDocumentWriter` moved to `GraphQL.IDocumentWriter`.
2. JSON serialization was extracted into two different libraries, [GraphQL.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GraphQL.NewtonsoftJson/) and [GraphQL.SystemTextJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GraphQL.SystemTextJson/).

If you are using the [server](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/server) project, you will need to [update to 4.x.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GraphQL.Server.Transports.AspNetCore/4.0.1)

[See the 2.x to 3.0 upgrade guide](https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/docs/guides/migration3#json-parsing-and-serialization) if you have written your own middleware.

### Newtonsoft.Json Example

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

private static async Task ExecuteAsync(HttpContext context, ISchema schema)
{
    GraphQLRequest request;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body))
    using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
    {
        var ser = new JsonSerializer();
        request = ser.Deserialize<GraphQLRequest>(jsonReader);
    }

    var executer = new DocumentExecuter();
    var result = await executer.ExecuteAsync(options =>
    {
        options.Schema = schema;
        options.Query = request.Query;
        options.OperationName = request.OperationName;
        options.Inputs = request.Variables.ToInputs();
    });

    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    context.Response.StatusCode = result.Errors?.Any() == true ? (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest : (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;

    var writer = new GraphQL.NewtonsoftJson.DocumentWriter();
    await writer.WriteAsync(context.Response.Body, result);
}

public class GraphQLRequest
{
    public string OperationName { get; set; }
    public string Query { get; set; }
    public Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject Variables { get; set; }
}
```

### System.Text Example

```
using System.Text.Json;

private static async Task ExecuteAsync(HttpContext context, ISchema schema)
{
    var request = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<GraphQLRequest>
    (
        context.Request.Body,
        new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true }
    );

    var executer = new DocumentExecuter();
    var result = await executer.ExecuteAsync(options =>
    {
        options.Schema = schema;
        options.Query = request.Query;
        options.OperationName = request.OperationName;
        options.Inputs = request.Variables.ToInputs();
    });

    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    context.Response.StatusCode = 200; // OK

    var writer = new GraphQL.SystemTextJson.DocumentWriter();
    await writer.WriteAsync(context.Response.Body, result);
}

public class GraphQLRequest
{
    public string OperationName { get; set; }

    public string Query { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(GraphQL.SystemTextJson.ObjectDictionaryConverter))]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Variables { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Joe McBride, I am a novice to ASP.Net Core & GraphQL. I am also having the same issue with version 5.3.00. I can not understand the solution as failed to determine any action point, and therefore asking for community help or some more explanation to resolve this issue!